# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Getting this Error In Xamarin Form Android Project I am refering Entity framework library int android project. Error as below

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'EntityFramework.dll' at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver) RadLoc.Android C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets
>   1500

I am stuck here please help me out of this..

Comment: EF6 is not compatible with Xamarin/Android. Use EF Core.

Comment: @magicandre1981 My EF ref in another C# Class Library and I am giving this C# library ref to my xamarin portable class library. and this Portable class library ref to my Android Project. No direct ref of EF to my Android Project

Comment: this doesn't matter, you still have a reference to EF6 which can't be resolved. rewrite the DAL with EF Core or host Webservice (WCF, SignalR) with old EF6 and consume the service in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @magicandre1981 said. Entity Framework doesn't fit in Xamarin.Android project. You need to use [EntityFramework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).

For a simple jump in and brief introduction, you can refer to [Building Android Apps with Entity Framework](https://blog.xamarin.com/building-android-apps-with-entity-framework/).

Answer (score 1):

For a windows application with this error:

If your copying the exe to a different folder from /bin/
You also need to include a copy of the application .config file along with the EntityFramework.xml and EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml files.